# Linear Discriminant Analysis- Derivation of Discriminant Function

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, discriminant-analysis

Given that, we want to maximize the posterior probability, for the expression (1) for k, I wan't to know how the expression (2) is obtained:
[image]

My understanding (may be wrong) is that the expansion should be like this:
[image]
How (3) and (4) are equal?

The article that i'm reading is from https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats202/notes/Classification/LDA.html.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu = (x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu)^T=\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x$ because it is a scalar and transposing it has no effect. Note that, since $\Sigma$ is symmetric, so as $\Sigma^{-1}$.

Therefore, the last term (4) reduces to $x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k$.